# Add multithreads/concurency in script

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I created a script which checks healthcheck and ports status from a .json file populated with microservices.
So for every microservice from the .json file the script will output the HTTP status and healthcheck body and other small details, and I want to add multithreading here in order to return all the output at once.Please see the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
... get the environment argument part...

file = File.read('./services.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

threads = []
service = data_hash.keys
service.each do |microservice|
threads << Thread.new do
  begin
  puts "Microservice: #{microservice}"
  port = data_hash["#{microservice}"]['port']
  puts "Port: #{port}"

  nodes = "knife search 'chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}' -i"
  node = %x[ #{nodes} ].split
    node.each do |n|
    puts "Node: #{n}"
    uri = URI("http://#{n}:#{port}/healthcheck?count=10")
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    status = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    puts res.code
    puts status
    puts res.message
  end

rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  puts "ReadTimeout Error"
  next
end
end
end
threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Anyway in this way the script return first the puts "Microservice: #{microservice}" and puts "Port: #{port}" and after this it will return the nodes and only after the STATUS.
How can I return all the data for each loop together?

Comment: Vlad, check out the `map` method, it's very handy.  You can simplify your code by doing: `threads = service.map...`.  Also, `service` should probably be named `services` to indicate plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `puts` write output to a variable (hash).
If you wand to wait for all threads to finish their job before showing the output, use `ThreadsWait` class.

```
require 'thwait'
file = File.read('./services.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

h = {}
threads = []
service = data_hash.keys
service.each do |microservice|
threads << Thread.new do
  thread_id = Thread.current.object_id.to_s(36)
  begin
  h[thread_id] = "Microservice: #{microservice}"
  port = data_hash["#{microservice}"]['port']
  h[thread_id] << "Port: #{port}"

  nodes = "knife search 'chef_environment:#{env} AND recipe:#{microservice}' -i"
  node = %x[ #{nodes} ].split
    node.each do |n|
    h[thread_id]<< "Node: #{n}"
    uri = URI("http://#{n}:#{port}/healthcheck?count=10")
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    status = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    h[thread_id] << res.code
    h[thread_id] << status
    h[thread_id] << res.message
  end

rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  h[thread_id] << "ReadTimeout Error"
  next
end
end
end
threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end

# wait untill all threads finish their job
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)

p h
```

[edit]

`ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)` is redundant in above code and can be omitted, since line `treads.each do |thread| thread.join end` does exactely the same thing.

Comment: Yes is working, thanks a lot for the ideea, basically it returns a HASH like this {"8x694"=>"Microservice: microservice1Port: 27580Node: node404{\"...

Comment: The threads join can be implemented more concisely as `threads.each(&:join)`.  Doesn't this already wait for all threads to complete?  What does `ThreadsWait` add?

Comment: Vlad, you're right.  The strings should have new lines at the end (like mine should have). Also, something I've found to be handy is that instead of building a string, to build a hash, with descriptive key names.  Then you can use awesome_print to output them in a very readable way.

Comment: @KeithBennett Bennett `threads.each(&:join)` doesn't wait for all threads to complete. It runs the threads and continues executing code in next line. In this case, when you `p h` without `ThreadsWait..` you will see that the hash does not contain complete output.

Comment: @maicher I don't understand why you say that.  This is *exactly* what `Thread#join` does, is it not?  From the docs at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html: "The calling thread will suspend execution and run this thread."  Try this: `p Time.now; t1 = Thread.new { sleep(3) }; t2 = Thread.new { sleep(5) }; [t1, t2].each(&:join); p Time.now`

Comment: You're right. `ThreadsWait` is not necessary in this case. In your example `[t1, t2].each(&:join)` gives exactly the same effect as  `ThreadsWait.all_waits(t1, t2)`. Thank's for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting the data as you get it using `puts`, you can collect it all in a string and then `puts` it once at the end.  Strings can take the `<<` operator (implemented as a method in Ruby), so you can just initialize the string, add to it, and then output it at the end, like this:

```
report = ''
report << 'first thing'
report << 'second thing'
puts report
```

You could even save them all up together and print them all after all were finished if you want.

Comment: I tried this solution also and is working , any ideea how to break this to view each item on a new line?

Comment: Change report to array: `report = []` and then in the end `puts report.join("\n")`